# MDX returns no value but want Null or N/A

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, ssrs-tablix, ssas-2008

I am new to SSAS(MDX) Side and using MDX to populate report in SSRS.
1) In my report I used Tablix which runs through MDX Script,
2) while the report execute the MDX not return any value so in report side it would create blank space. Instead of blank space I need some values like (N/A).

Plese provide some guidence in SSRS side else need some input to modify MDX such a way that if there in no value it will return Null (or some other value like x or N/A).

Appreciated you Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Answer , the MDX which i am using to generate data have NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN, and due this it wont populate the empty records so I removed the NONEMPTY and Left CROSSJOIN as it is and the megic happend.

Appreciated you help Alwaysariyana.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iif function so you check if the value exists and if it doesn't, "N/A", else the value.  This should work on MDX expressions as well.

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!YourField.Value),"N/A",Fields!YourField.Value)
```